# uilabel not the same height as uiimage with the same height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

Im trying to put an image behind a uilabel and need both to be about the same height (the uiimageview a little bigger to surround uilabel) and I have given both the same height in cgrectmake but yet the uiimageview remains smaller than the uilabel even though they are set to the same height.Please help! Code:

```
UILabel *labelEntry = [[UILabel alloc]init];
labelEntry.numberOfLines = 0;
labelEntry.text = entry;
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [entry sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.f, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
CGRect lblFrame =  CGRectMake(13, 30, 320, expectedLabelSize.height);
labelEntry.frame = lblFrame;
labelEntry.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
labelEntry.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 17.0];
labelEntry.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
labelEntry.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

[image]

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 30, 320, expectedLabelSize.height)];
backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"postl.png"];
[scrollView addSubview:backgroundImage];
```

Comment: What size is the image and what content mode is the image view?

Comment: The content mode is UIViewContentModeScaleToFill and the size of the image is 312 x 164

Comment: If you want to include images in your question make sure you don't indent them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

From your image(postl.png) what i can notice is, there is shadow effect applied to the image. Try once by setting background color for the **imageview** & you can see the shadow of applied image. Later you can adjust the frames accordingly

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of post1.png? If it is not the same size as your CGRect you will need to stretch it. That would include changing your UIImageView's contentMode and possibly creating a stretchable image.

Comment: I thought cgrect would stretch it, and the size of the image is 312 x 164

Comment: That depends on the contentMode of the image view etc.

Comment: What would be an appropiate contentMode for the imageview? i have tried several all to no avial

Comment: Most likely UIViewContentModeScaleToFill but it depends on your image.

Comment: I have found that the image is stretching beyond its actual dimensions  but just not to the correct height as specified, other labels that i have on the scroll view with several paragraphs of text have the uiimage view stretched (but not at the same height as the label)